# Need to evaluate TeeChartNET2015EVAL_4.1.2015.12166.exe with Framework 3.5

Tags: teechart

Looks like when I run TeeChartNET2015EVAL_4.1.2015.12166.exe, it installs version of TeeChart.dll built on framework 4.5 only. I need to do the evaluation  with the dll built with framework 3.5 (because I have to integrate to an already existing application based on Framework 3.5). Is there any way I can get the evaluation dll for Framework 3.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When running the installer you need to choose which environments do you want the assemblies for. If you choose Visual Studio 2008 this will install .NET Framework 3.5 assemblies as this is the default framework supported by this environment.